# Set Stored Procedure Variables based on the execution status of the last run/runs of SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having a SQL Server Job **LoadDataIntoSQLTable** running once daily, that executes the SP **usp_UpsertData**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpsertData
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            DECLARE @maxDate DATE
            /*If the job is running today i.e., on 24th November, then @maxDate should be 23rd October*/
            SELECT @maxDate = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @errorMsg NVARCHAR(MAX),
                @errorSeverity INT
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SELECT @errorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        RAISERROR(@errorMsg, @errorSeverity, 1)
    END CATCH
END
```

Now, if the Job failed yesterday, then my @maxDate should be:

```
/*If the job failed yesterday i.e., on 23rd November, then the @maxDate should be 22nd October*/
SELECT @maxDate = DATEADD(dd, -2, DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
```

I've achieved the above by including an IF EXISTS in my code as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpsertData
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            DECLARE @maxDate DATE
            /*If the job is running today i.e., on 24th November, then @maxDate should be 23rd October*/
            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
                      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs s
                      ON h.job_id = s.job_id
                      WHERE s.name = 'LoadDataIntoSQLTable'
                      AND h.run_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE()-1, 112)
                      AND step_id = 1
                      and h.run_status = 0)
            BEGIN
                SELECT @maxDate = DATEADD(dd, -2, DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
            END
            ELSE
                SELECT @maxDate = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @errorMsg NVARCHAR(MAX),
                @errorSeverity INT
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SELECT @errorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        RAISERROR(@errorMsg, @errorSeverity, 1)
    END CATCH
END
```

Now, this is working fine. But, what if the job is constantly failing for 2-3 or more days? If the job failed yesterday and day before yesterday also, then my @maxDate should be 21st October and so on. I hope, I was able to explain the logic of @maxDate.

Need help to determine @maxDate if the job is failing constantly for more than 1 day.

Any sort of help is going to appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: *"Need help to determine @maxDate if the job is failing constantly for more than 1 day."* If the job is failing, it'll show in the logs; that the best way to find out. I would also recommend setting on Operators in the SQL Server Agent, so that they can be notified in the event of a failure too, then you are aware and can address the failure ASAP.

Comment: Side Note: Why use `RAISERROR`? It's recommended (by the documentation) to use `THROW` in new development work.

Comment: Operators are set, and we are getting notified in the event of failures. But on the next day, the SP should get the start from the maxDate of the previous execution in the case of failure. It needs to be done automatically, no manual intervention should be there

Comment: There is few other logic like Insert/Update. On the occurrence of failure, need to display failure in SQL Server Agent History, that is why RAISERROR. If RAISERROR was not present the job would have completed successfully, even in the case of failure.

Comment: *"On occurrence of a failure, need to rollback the changes, that's why raise error"* Rolling back errors has nothing to do with `RAISERROR`. See the very first statement in [RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"The **RAISERROR** statement does not honor **SET XACT_ABORT**. New applications should use **THROW** instead of **RAISERROR**."*

Comment: Then, to answer your qusetion, `SELECT @maxDate = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))` is *always* doing to return the date 1 day and 1 minute ago (1441 minutes ago). `GETDATE()` doesn't care about if a task failure yesterday. You'll need to implement a logging table to ensure the correct day is used.

Comment: Store the run date in a table. When the job execeutes successfully you increment the run date, ready for the next run. If it fails you don't

Comment: "Store the run date in a table. When the job execeutes successfully you increment the run date, ready for the next run. If it fails you don't" Sure Nick, this can be an option, but I was thinking that if this could be achievable without creating an extra table in the Db. If this could be done using the table msdb.sysjobhistory, then it would be great.